# My XMLHttpRequest duration increases with every request. What to do?

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, xmlhttprequest, duration

My XMLHttpRequest JavaScript Callback duration increases with every call. What to do?

I am running google tracer, it puzzles me, i have no idea how to contain it, its just, increases, by some 60ms, by the time i on 15th request, it takes up to 6 seconds and longer for browser to finish rendering.

I have small xml powered js app, that loads xml files and renderes out page portion based on daat in xml file.

Any suggestions?

**CODE:**

```
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: path,
                        dataType: "xml",
                        success: function(xml) {
                            XMLDATASTORAGE = $(xml);
                            scaffoldingMarkUp(type);
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            scaffoldingMarkUp('error');
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, i found my EVAL code : / freaking CUFON refresh..... aaaaa.

it was part of function which is executed on ajax success.. omg... such a simple piece of **** but how much headache.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange. You could try using the same XmlHttpRequest (`xhr`) object for every request, like this:

```
var xhr = $.ajax(...)
```

And in the next call, use the same, like this:

```
xhr = $.ajax({
  ...
  xhr: function(){
     return xhr;
  }
});
```

So If your XmlHttp is consuming many resources, it'll be overwritten and 'reused' in every ajax call.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: unfortunately this was not it, although you helped me make this prone to any type of caching. I had cufon.refresh running in call back function that was part of the success...